# Blazor Toaster Notifications - Doubling up

Tags: blazor, toast

Firstly I have coded with .Net MVC but Blazor seems to be the better fit for this project. It's a Blazor Server App using .Net 7.

So I am using Blazored.Toast to handle notifications when certain elements happen. The problem I have is that the message loads twice and I am pulling my hair out why.

Please be brutal if I am making a mess of things.

Thank you,
Richard

```
@page "/customer-manage/{CustomerId:guid}"
@layout SwordfishLayout
@inject IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> Context
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IToastService ToastService

<div class="p-4">
    <HeaderTextComponent Text="Manage Customer"></HeaderTextComponent>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white">
                    <h6>Customer Details</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                   <CustomerManagerComponent CustomerId="CustomerId"></CustomerManagerComponent>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white">
                    <h6>Address Details</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <AddressManagerService CustomerId="@CustomerId" AddressId="@AddressId"></AddressManagerService>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var db = Context.CreateDbContext();
        this.Customer = await db.Customers.FindAsync(this.CustomerId);
        this.AddressId = this.Customer.AddressId.Value;
        ShowToaster();
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void ShowToaster()
    {
        ToastService.ShowInfo(Toastr.MessageContent(Toastr.MessageType.EmailHasBeenSent), "We'll be in touch soon");
    }
}
```

I have tried both the On Initialize and On Parameter Set methods. Id expect the Toastr to only show once.

Comment: Is this Blazor server with pre-rendering?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the `ServerPrerendered` mode. When using this your method will be called twice. Once during prerendering and once it has been delivered to the client.

You can change the rendering mode for your app to Server this should fix your issue. This can be achivied within the _Host.cshtml file.

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
```